# Multi-user IPython Authentication/Security

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to setup an IPython notebook cluster, hosted on somewhere in the Interwebz, to be used by me, some co-workers and one of my kids, each having their own notebook. However, given that IPython executes python commands in the host machine, I only want to allow certain people to have access to it. Is there a way to have this sort of setup to require some sort of authentication without having to install or setup apache or some other framework?

Answer (score 5):

[Edit Feb 2015]

The relevant project to run multi-user IPython notebook is to use [JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub) (Note: IPython has been partially renamed Jupyter). JupyterHub has a pluggable architecture that handle various auth, and remote spawning of process, as well as user redirection.

---

[This part is not relevant anymore]

Not baked in IPython (yet), is is in the roadmap for the next 2 years.
You can start one notebook instance per user (but then you don't share notebook), each on a different port. You can have a look at [IPython-Hydra](https://github.com/cni/ipython-hydra) that more or less does it automatically. If you have issues with multiple port, you can host multiple notebook server using prefix and [ipython notebook proxy](https://npmjs.org/package/ipython-notebook-proxy) I didn't had time to have it support https yet, but it is recommended if you host it on public ip.

Comment: There is now a Python port of Hydra with a bit more functionality: https://github.com/UnataInc/ipydra